# R: Sample a vector with replacement multiple times

Tags: r

I'd like to sample a vector x of length 7 with replacement and sample that vector 10 separate times.  I've tried the something like the following but can't get the resulting 7x10 output I'm looking for.  This produces a 1x7 vector but I can't figure out to get the other 9 vectors

```
x <- runif(7, 0, 1)
for(i in 1:10){
    samp <- sample(x, size = length(x), replace = T)
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a very convenient way to do this:

```
replicate(10,sample(x,length(x),replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you seem to want to sample with replacement, you can just get the 7*10 samples at once (which is more efficient for large sizes):

```
x <- runif(7)
n <- 10
xn <- length(x)
matrix(x[sample.int(xn, xn*n, replace=TRUE)], nrow=xn)

# Or slightly shorter:
matrix(sample(x, length(x)*n, replace=TRUE), ncol=n)
```

The second version uses `sample` directly, but there are some issues with that: if `x` is a numeric of length 1, bad things happen. `sample.int` is safer.

```
x <- c(pi, -pi)
sample(x, 5, replace=T) # OK
x <- pi
sample(x, 5, replace=T) # OOPS, interpreted as 1:3 instead of pi...
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got a suitable answer, but here's an approach that's similar to your first attempt. The difference is that we define `samp` with the appropriate dimensions, and then iteratively index into that object and fill it one row at a time:

```
samp <- matrix(NA, ncol = 7, nrow = 10)
for(i in 1:10){
  samp[i,] <- sample(x, size = length(x), replace = T)
}
```